# Dismiss UIActionSheet from AppDelegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiactionsheet

In my view, I have an actionsheet that may be presented from a UIBarButton (iPad).  If user goes to homescreen and back, app shows a lock screen wehre user must enter password for security.  But if the popover wasn't dismised before going into background, it is still showing on top of lockscreen.  The UIActionSheet is a property of that VC, not the App Delegate.

The method in my delegate is:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"STATUS - Application did become active");
    [[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setDelegate:nil];
    [_notActiveTimer invalidate];
    _notActiveTimer = nil;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"_application_background" object:self userInfo:NULL];

    LockScreen *vc = [[[LockScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"LockScreen" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    vc.showFullUsernamePasswordLogin = TRUE;
    [self.splitView presentModalViewController:vc animated: YES];
}
```

Code:

```
- (IBAction)showeRXActionSheet:(id)sender
{
    if (self.actionSheet != nil) {
        [self.actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];
    }

    if (!self.eRXActionSheet)
    {
        UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"eRX Menu" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"New eRX", @"eRX Refills", nil];
        sheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
        self.eRXActionSheet = sheet;
        [sheet release];

        [self.eRXActionSheet showFromBarButtonItem:sender animated:YES];

        return;
    }

    [self.eRXActionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:self.eRXActionSheet.cancelButtonIndex animated:YES];
    self.eRXActionSheet = nil;
}

- (IBAction)actionButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    if (self.eRXActionSheet != nil) {
        [self.eRXActionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];
    }

    if (!self.actionSheet)
    {
        UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Action Menu" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Help", @"Lock", @"Log Out", nil];
        sheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
        self.actionSheet = sheet;
        [sheet release];

        [self.actionSheet showFromBarButtonItem:sender animated:YES];

        return;
    }

    [self.actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:self.actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex animated:YES];
    self.actionSheet = nil;
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (actionSheet == self.eRXActionSheet)
    {
        if (buttonIndex == 0)
        {
            [self erxButtonClicked];
        }
        else if (buttonIndex == 1)
        {
            [self erxRefillButtonClicked];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (buttonIndex == 0)
        {
            [self helpButtonClicked];
        }
        else if (buttonIndex == 1)
        {
            [self lockButtonClicked];
        }
        else if (buttonIndex == 2)
        {
            [self logOut];
        }
    }
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    self.eRXActionSheet = nil;
    self.actionSheet = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want.

```
-(void)dismissSheet{
    if (self.actionSheet){
        [self.actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];
    }
}

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(dismissSheet) name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];
        // Your other setup code
}
```

you could also use the `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification`, what ever makes sense for you application flow.

remember to remove observer in dealloc.

Comment: The VC that presents the actionsheet is not lockscreen vc.  The lockscreen VC is the VC that is shown when the app is brought back from backrgound and is loaded ontop of whatever vc was already there as a pincode check.

Comment: That's fine. Work that code into the the view controller that presents and has reference to the actionSheet. When your application resigns active it will dismiss the actionSheet and upon your return it will no longer be presented.

Comment: Worked! Is this what I put in dealloc? `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];`

Comment: Yes. Or you can just removeObserver:self that way if later you find a need to add another observer you can't forget to remove it.